# One of my clients is paying me to teach her to do her job. Her employer really should be paying. Do I contact them to offer my services?

Tags: freelancing

If I should,  at all?

I am a specialist in a specific niche technology and I work as a contractor for anyone who needs help/advice, etc.

I was hired by someone who is way out of their depth at work. They work in the same field as me, but don't have nearly as much experience. After answering their questions and helping them out (no company IP involved) it became clear to both of us that she is way out of her depth. She is basically paying me to help her learn to do her job.

I told her that it really is the company's responsibility to train her, and she shouldn't be paying me to help. She has no colleagues to help her and has been thrown in the deep end with a very difficult tool.

I told her she needs to have a discussion with her employer about getting more training and having more time to learn. She said she will. She said she was worried about losing her job.

I was wondering if it should contact them directly offering my services. I am available to work for them and then they can pay me for a month or so to teach her.

I would be clear that she contacted me and asked me some questions and it was clear she needs help. However i have some concerns.

- I dont want to steal her job. What if they hire me and fire her? I can't be there physically, I'm at the other end of the world. Someone needs to be there.
- Should I mention her at all? I don't want to be deceitful and pretend I happened upon their career page, and then it comes out she and I know eachother.
- What if I do nothing and she tells me she's lost her job. It feels bad to contact them then. But it's good work, and I'm a perfect match for the job. At that point the job is theoretically fair game, but I'd still feel sorry for her.
- Should i just stay out of it? I need work myself but if it is inappropriate for me to contact them it's inevitable i will find work somewhere else.
- The company is dutch, so I have no idea if that has a cultural impact too.
- Do i tell her that I'm going to contact them? What if she thinks I'm trying to steal her job? Should I check with her first?

She is first and foremost my client, and I really want to do right by her, as I want to do with all my clients. She very clearly needs this job. I can get work elsewhere. I don't want to jeopardize her job by being careless so i don't want to make a mistake.

Should I contact them and offer my services? If so, do I mention she hired me?

Comment: "I told her that it really is the company's responsibility to train her..." - You do not know that. If she represented herself to have these skills, and she was hired and compensation set based on her assertion, then the company has **NO** duty to train her, and it might even be cause for her termination if you tell the company she needs this training.

Comment: I cannot stress the importance of NOT contacting this employer, she will have to learn how to swim eventually, she can’t pay you indefinitely.

Answer (score 14):

Your business relationship between you and her is just that, it's between you and her. She hired you. She is your client.

Any potential issues here are between her and her employer, not between you and her employer. What they choose to do and what job training they offer her is frankly none of your business.

Now if you're interested in obtaining a job with her employer then by all means do so, but not under the guise of "She's been paying me to help her learn how to do her job so I thought I'd reach out and offer my services directly to you."... because that's irrelevant as far as I see it.

Comment: Something just smells "conflict of interest" but I'm not even sure how to put it. It's like a manufacturer poaching clients from their own distributors and doing direct sales.

Comment: Breach of confidentiality, certainly.